# How does $ \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ imply $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left((f(x) - f(a) \right) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

In one of the calculus videos I'm watching, the instructor claims that

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a) \Longleftrightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to a} \left((f(x) - f(a) \right) = 0 \tag{1}$$

How is this equivalence established?

I can see how

$$ \left(\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \right) - f(a) = 0 $$

would follow from the left part of $(1)$, but I don't know what additional steps to take to  end up with the right part. Does it follow from the limit laws somehow?

Comment: Simply distribute the limit on the R.H.S. Remember that f(a) is a constant.

Comment: Can I just substitute $a$ for $x$ in the left part? And then claim that $\lim\limits_{x \to a } (f(a) - f(a)) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} 0 = 0 $?

Comment: You can substitute since the limit exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\lim_{x \to a}(f(x) - f(a)) = 0$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to a}f(x)-\lim_{x \to a}f(a) = 0$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(a)$$

Here, notice that $f(a)$ is just a constant so $\lim_{x \to a}f(a) = f(a)$. Then the result follows.

Comment: This is the only answer I can follow, but it only shows how the right part implies the left part. Still don't know how the left part implies the right part.

Comment: Just reverse the implication arrows in the answer.

Comment: I was going to right it long but what @avs said perfectly makes sense and it is much shorter. Maybe, I should have used $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence is established via the theorem that says

> If $f(x),g(x)$ are functions defined in a neighbourhood of $x=a$, and the limits
>   $\lim_{x\to a}f(x), \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist, then the limit of the function $f-g$
>   as $x\to a$ also exists, and
>   $$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

In your case $g(x)$ is the constant function $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers of @Arsenberk and @uniquesolution are perfectly correct, in applying a more general result, I’ll go shallow and point out that after you write $f(a)=c$, some unspecified constant, it’s saying that the statement “$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=c$” is equivalent to “$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-c)=0$”.

But when you write out the definition of these two, both say exactly the same thing, namely
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\text{ such that }\forall x\text{ with }|x-a|<\delta, \text{ you get }|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this. Look at what the hypothesis tells you about the first term on the left. Clearly $f(a) - f(a) = 0$. Nothing to do with limits any longer.